# How to make a spam tester

Tags: java, spring, email, jakarta-ee, email-spam

In my project I need to make a spam tester to check the spam score of the mails prepared to be sent. When I searched, I found Spam Assassin, which they say is used as sapm filters in many mail servers. Can I create a spam tester using Spam Assassin? Another option I found is one Litmus API, which is a paid service. Is there any options other than these two? Freeware is more preferred. My project is a J2EE web application using Spring.

Answer (score 5):

SpamAssasin is a **spam tester**. A lot of server-side email software integrate this. It's a standalone piece of software that runs and serves as a barrier to analyze incoming emails and flag them for their level of "spamminess"..

I feel like if you're using java you could benefit from a library such as http://www.jasen.org/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I checked the link. It shows the release year of jsen as 2005. Will it work effectively in current mail servers?

Answer (score 2):

You can also check the mail by sending it to check@isnotspam.com. That's a free service performing several verifications (SPF, DKIM, SenderId, SpamAssassin) and mailing back a report almost immediately.